# How to use copy_from_user?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

```
ssize_t probchar_write(struct file *filp, 
    const char __user *data, size_t s, loff_t *off) {

    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Data> |%s|\n", data); // only for debug
    char chars[MAX_LENGHT];
    if(s > MAX_LENGHT)
        s = MAX_LENGHT;
    if (copy_from_user(chars, data, s)) {
        return -EFAULT;
    }
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Chars> |%s|\n", chars);
    return s;
}
```

This is dmesg output

```
[66777.956582] Data> |45
[66777.956596] |
[66777.956634] Chars> |45
[66777.956636] �    Ҩ�H��   H�� |
```

Why the copied chain has more characters in the end?

Comment: the correct wording should be `MAX_LENGTH`, not `MAX_LENGHT` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a write function from a device driver.

First

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "Data> |%s|\n", data);
```

Do not do this! Do not ever directly access user data ever!

<strike>Second</strike>

```
char chars[s];
```

I doubt this is legal C. You need to either specify a size at compile time, or use kmalloc.

The copy_from_user usage is good. You should check for error and return -EFAULT. This is ok.

So just try and allocating the chars and it should work. You might also want to look at the offset, though for academic purposes that can be initially skipped.

Comment: Seems I need to catch up on my standard. The way he uses copy_from_user is then fine.

Comment: printk(KERN_DEBUG "Data> |%s|\n", data); was only for debug

Now I made the array with a fixed size, but the same thing keeps happening

Comment: From what I see you are using it correctly. What are you doing in user space?

Comment: Add a null terminator at the end of chars. chars[s] = '\0'; Alternatively you can make a program that opens /dev/probchar and write to it a null terminated string of size strlen(str).

Comment: Tanks it works perfect now, but strict_strtoul dont validate a very big long?
If I entrer echo "4543434443" > /dev/probchar it returns 248467147...

Comment: I don't know about strtoul, but from what I searched it seems you may want to add another l at the end. That number seems to be bigger then 2^32(unsigned int is usually the same as long). It can fit however in a long long. Try strict_strtoull for that number. I am not guaranteeing it.

Comment: It seems that 2^32 - 4543434443 = -248467147. So you need a bigger storage. Try long long.

Comment: yes, my idea was validate the input number with strict_strtoul... no use a bigger storage

Comment: Then pass it to strict_strtoull. Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: my idea was throw an error if the user enter a number greater than 2^32
Really thanks a lot!

Comment: anyoue has an idea how to do it?

Comment: Oh I thought you had everything cleared. Use what? You should think about making another question since I am probably the only one that still reads / receives alerts for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following: there is no `\0` at the end of the provided string. You don't add one or enforce one to be present. Then you print the string after copying the "valid" data on a stack-allocated buffer that contains random garbage. That makes extra characters being printed.

Suggested check: allocate MAX_LENGTH+1 characters and after you copied the data, do `chars[s]=0`. 
You might want to strip that `\n` character that kills the formatting of your log, too.